# How to split registration and media?

Tags: fedora, centos, freebsd, voip, sip

I have a SIP project. Where i will have SIP server running.

Server will do following:

- will only do routing and receive incoming calls
- But the audio/video will be peer 2 peer

Can this be done with Asterisk? Only the media i have to split but the registration will be with Server.

Tools:
A) server with SIP 
B) One PC with SIP client
C) Anoher PC with SIP client

- My goal is: B and C gets connected via A and audio/video packets are not via A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is how the SIP protocol works.  The SIP server just sets up the call.  The clients then talk direct to each other.  [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol) tells you all about it.